# Questions about state history plugin with fill-postgresql (history-tools)

Tags: history

I'm trying to build full-history eos nodes with state-history plugin.
My decision is using eosio/history-tools which utilizes postgreSQL.

But my question is, I can't find any options for postgresQL endpoint.
There's an option for nodeos endpoint, but I can't find postgreSQL one.

Remote access to DB is required because I want to separate DBMS server from others (for using standalone DBMS cloud service).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer:

Just set PG* environment variables. If so, fill-pg will use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fill-pg from this repo:

https://github.com/EOSIO/history-tools

fill-pg will connect to nodeos, pull data and fill the Postgres instance